# Need help getting specific character through user input

Tags: python, string, slice

I been trying to learn python a month and a half thu my uni course for my cs degree(1st year) so try to go a lil easy, i decided to redo from where i had problems

This is the question being asked
'''Given a string (someString) and an int (removeChar), create a new variable (newString)
where the char at index removeChar has been removed. Return newString.

Sounds simple but i cant wrap my head around outputting the newstring without the user inputted character

I know to use string slicing but i dont fully see how to use it with taking out the character and making the new string without it.

if i do

```
somestring = Alex

newstring = somestring[removechar:]
```

lets say the remove char is 2, the output is ex

however if i do

```
somestring = Alex
newstring = somestring[:removechar]
```

I get the output of Al

after that you would think okay so if removechar: is ex and :removechar is al then e is the letter thats changing the whole string.

But if i do [removechar:removechar] then it should take out the one letter but it doesnt nothing is in the output now. So i cant do it like that

I have to use string slicing for this question bc the time we would be doing this we wouldnt be able to use lists, replace, or translate

What am i missing here that you guys all see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this works is it gets all character(s) before the letter you want to remove and then because it is a string it adds that with all the character(s) after the letters you want to remove. The reason we add 1 is because if we do not it will include the letter you want to remove.

```py
def remove(removeCharindx, string):
    newString = string[:removeCharindx] + string[removeCharindx+1:]
    return newString

print(remove(1, "Alex"))
```